# how to explicitely give priorities to the queues with python-rq

Tags: python-rq

I am trying python-rq and I do not see how to explicitely give priorities to the queues?

Does the priority come from the order they are defined when the worker is launched?

```
rqworker queueA queueB queueC
```

queueA is prioritized compare to queueB and queueC ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are right.

The order of the arguments `queueA`, `queueB`, `queueC` defines the priority.

For more details - http://python-rq.org/docs/workers/

Comment: In the link you gave, there is literraly nothing bout priority. The docs vaguely say tha you can put something into config `QUEUES = ['high', 'default', 'low']`

Comment: @Verthais the order of the queues in the list defines the priority. The first item gets the highest priority, while the second item gets the second highest priority and so on.